# All duplicate records need to be removed... ( if a row has a duplicate, then both rows need to be deleted )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables **`table1`** and **`table2`**.

Both of them are identical, except that `table2` has no primary key or constraints.

I need to copy data from `table2` to `table1`.

`table1` does **not** accept duplicate rows.

The primary key in `table1` is based on 5 columns: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`.

`table2` has a bunch of duplicated rows.

I am able to get the duplicated rows in `table2` using:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'Occurence' col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM table2
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

And I am able to delete one duplicate using the query below:

```
WITH cte
AS ( SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 ORDER BY col1 ) AS [rn]
FROM table2
)
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1
```

But what I want is to delete all the duplicates which are found.

To make it clear there are two rows:

```
            Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
            1       2       3       4       5       TEXAS
            1       2       3       4       5       NEW YORK
```

So the first query posted above will give me a result as:

```
Occurence   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
2           1       2       3       4       5
```

The second query will delete any one of the above ( i.e. either TEXAS or NEW YORK ).
I want to delete both TEXAS and NEW YORK.

And my tables are this way:

`table1` has **x** number of rows.

`table2` has **x + y** number of rows i.e. it has all the rows of `table1` plus some.

Taking the above example,

TEXAS is available in both `table1` and `table2`.

And TEXAS occurs twice in `table2`.

But NEW YORK is available in only `table2`.

When I copy the data from `table2` to `table1` only NEW YORK can be inserted ( should be inserted ).

With a **`DISTINCT`** query or when **`rn > 1`** TEXAS will still be there ( occurs once ) in `table2` and the **`INSERT`** will fail.

Comment: You are trying to delete all the entries (same in 5 columns) that occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION BY` u can get the dupliacted rows. With the help of `Delete from Inner JOIN` table and `CTE` you can delete the duplicated rows.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,
                Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
                    ORDER BY col1) AS [rn]
         FROM   table2)
DELETE A
FROM   table2 a
       JOIN cte b
         ON a.col1 = b.col1
            AND a.col2 = b.col2
            AND a.col3 = b.col3
            AND a.col4 = b.col4
            AND a.col5 = b.col5
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CTE, You just deleted the rows that are not equal to 1. So, it didn't allow to delete any one of Texas or New york. I slightly changed your query and get the Max of [rn] and deleted the rows having max > 1.

```
WITH cte
AS 
(
SELECT  col1,col2,col3,col4, col5, MAX(rn) AS Max FROM (SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4, col5,
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3,col4, col5 ORDER BY col1) AS [rn]
FROM table2) AS Table1 GROUP BY col1,col2,col3,col4, col5
)

DELETE cte WHERE [Max] > 1
```

Try this.

Comment: I actually used > 1. And what I want is: delete all rows when rn for that row is > 1.

Comment: So you want to delete record having rn > 1. What your query did?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to delete anything from table2 if all that's needed is load data into table1. The following query should suffice.

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
SELECT * FROM table2 otr
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT 1
                FROM table2 inr
                WHERE inr.col1=otr.col1
                AND inr.col2=otr.col2
                AND inr.col3=otr.col3
                AND inr.col4=otr.col4
                AND inr.col5=otr.col5
                GROUP BY inr.col1,
                         inr.col2,
                         inr.col3,
                         inr.col4,
                         inr.col5
                HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```